# Has anyone been able to play a video file and show live camera feed at the same time in separate views on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2, ios5

I have been trying to do this for a few days now using AVFoundation as well as trying to use MPMoviePlayerViewController.  The closest I can get is allowing one to play at a time.  I would like to think that this is possible because of Facetime.  However, I know this is a little different because there is no separate video file.

Any ideas would help, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where this is documented, but to get `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play together at the same time you need to set a mixable audio session category first.

Here's one way to do that:

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
UInt32 mixable = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(mixable), &mixable);
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

See the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide) and [Audio Session Cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW1) for more info.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. Are you sure you're setting a mixable audio session category?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to play video on one thread and recording video on another? That would allow both of them to run while maintaining their separation.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the right direction to go.  Would you be able to point me to an example as to how this would be implemented correctly.  So I can see if this will work, and I'll accept your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be hard for me to explain it in a really concise example... Threading is one of those things that you have to go out and learn (like Core Data, if you have learned how to use in a similar as the one I used, it basically consisted of reading through Apple Docs to find out how to work it)
So, here is the link to the Apple Documentation for setting up and implementing threads: Good Luck!
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html